# Iterating through all public members of an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, class, properties, instance-variables, instanceof

I have a class called foo. Foo has hundreds of properties. I have a list(of foo) that contains all my instances of foo. I want to loop through all the foo instances, and list all the property names and values for each instance. pseudocode:

```
for i as integer = 0 to foolist.count - 1
   for each prop as property in foolist.item(i)
      outstring.add(prop.name, prop.value)
   each
each
```

Answer (score 1):

Whats the question here?

Suggest to use Linq/lambda instead of regular For Loop with "Parallel.For each" and "synclock" within the property fetching. Also instead of outstring use KeyValue Pair type to store result properties. A ReadOnly list of result could enhance performance too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to find the properties and get the values.  The performance may not be great for a large list.

```
' Get the list of properties 
Dim props = GetType(Foo).GetProperties()

For Each f In foolist
    ' Show the value for each property
    For Each p In props
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", p.Name, p.GetValue(f))
    Next
Next
```